# Dock Icons Specific To Workspace

Tags: dock, mission-control

I love working in new spaces however is there a way to have Dock Icons be specific to each workspace, say for example I have the following workspaces

```
Workspace 1
Terminal, Safari

Workspace 2
Terminal, Safari, TextEdit
```

Would it be possible to have each workspace only display icons in the dock for the applications it has within it?

Comment: Not natively, but you can quickly show all windows in a Space using the special key on F3, or ctrl/up arrow, or [I think] 3-finger swipe up… I don't have a trackpad to test that one] More options in System Prefs > Mission Control; Keyboard/Keyboard & Shortcuts [& probably Trackpad]

Comment: Yeah I know how to do that, I was just hoping there would be a way to minimise the amount of dock icons, as I don't need a terminal icon for each terminal open if that makes sense, just once to show that I have an amount of terminals open